# JAVA: Unable to return response in loop

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I unable to loop my response. It always return me as:

```
"data": [
        {
            "mydata1": "data 1",
            "mydata2": "data 2"
        }
    ],
```

It suppose to return as below:

```
"data": [
        {
            "mydata1": "data 1",
            "mydata2": "data 2"
        },
            "mydata1": "data 1",
            "mydata2": "data 2"
        },
            "mydata1": "data 1",
            "mydata2": "data 2"
        }
    ]
```

Below are my code:

```
      private List<myList> returnData;
      public List<myList> getReturnData() {
        return returnData;
      }
      public void setReturnData(final List<myList> returnData) {
        this.returnData = returnData;
      }

      public List<myList> listDetail(
        @Valid final ListRequest listRequest)
      throws MyException {
        for (final ListRequestDetail listRequestDetail : 
          ((ListRequest) listRequest).getData()) {
             setReturnData(myRepository.myDetails(
                listRequestDetail.getMyData1(),
                listRequestDetail.getMyData2()));
        } 
        return returnData;
      }
```

I able to POST, capture from log:

```
 Submit price for ListRequest (data=[ListRequestDetail (myData1=1.00, myData2=2.00), ListRequestDetail (myData1=1.00, myData2=2.00), ListRequestDetail (myData1=1.00, myData2=2.00)])
```

Please advice as my brain has already stop working. JAVA is really torturing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually re-initiating the `returnData` list in each iteration. Rather it should update the existing list. As below:

1) Initiate the `returnData` List once you enter in method `listDetail`.
2) Add new method `addReturnData` to update existing list.

```
  private List<myList> returnData;

  private void addReturnData(final List<myList> data) {
    this.returnData.addAll(data);
  }

  public void setReturnData(final List<myList> returnData) {
    this.returnData = returnData;
  }

  public List<myList> getReturnData() {
    return returnData;
  }

  public List<myList> listDetail(@Valid final ListRequest listRequest) throws MyException {

    returnData = new ArrayList<myList>();
    for (final ListRequestDetail listRequestDetail : ((ListRequest) listRequest).getData()) {
      addReturnData(myRepository.myDetails(listRequestDetail.getMyData1(), listRequestDetail.getMyData2()));
    }
    return returnData;
  }
```

Comment: My god.. thanks.. it works. so simple, I dont know why i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

SO you're running over `listRequestDetail` object, which, I assume has three elements.

In the loop you call `myRepository.myDetails(elem.getMyData1(), elem.getMyData2())` this is ok as long as you're ok with contacting the repository during each iteration. I'm paying your attention to this because you've mentioned hibernate in the question. The data will be different though.

But then you're doing something wrong.
When you get the result you call `setReturnData` effectively overriding the `returnData` after each iteration.

A side note here, this code is probably not multithreaded. If you maintain `private List<myList> returnData;` only to "gather" the results, you better define it inside the `listDetail` method and return so that the code will be able to work in multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting returnData in every loop and it finally sets to the last listRequestDetail values. Since you want returnData to consists all of the values from listRequest.getData(). You have to add the listRequestDetail to the returnData list. Try below Changes to your code

```
private List<MyList> returnData = new ArrayList<>();

public void addToReturnData(final List<myList> returnData) 
{this.returnData.addAll(returnData);}

 public List<MyList> listDetail(@Valid final ListRequest listRequest)
 throws MyException {
     for (final ListRequestDetail listRequestDetail : ((ListRequest) listRequest).getData()) {
  addToReturnData(myRepository.myDetails(listRequestDetail.getMyData1(), listRequestDetail.getMyData2()));
     } 
     return returnData;
 }
```